# Do Infested Terran benefit from unit upgrades?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

Do Infested Terran get any benefit from weapon/armour upgrades?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Team Liquid's [Liquipedia 2](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Infested_Terran) article, Infested Terran benefit from Zerg Ground Carapace and Zerg Missile Attacks. These attack upgrade benefits would be shared with the Roach, Hydralisk and Queen. While obviously the ground upgrades would benefit all zerg ground units.